# c or c++: specify return type when calling a function

Tags: c++, c

I saw some code specify the return type when calling a function, like this:

```
int main()
{
    (void)function(0);
    return 0;
}
```

What is its purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe some historical note for compiler optimizations, useless today.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Not really! This supresses compiler warnings about not using a value if you use all recommended warnings. E.g. for something like `volatile int i; ... (void)i;` this should be used, too.

Comment: It's an example of self-documenting code.  It's indicating, `"I know this returns something, but I don't care what it is."`.